# In a stored procedure, how can I use the results of one query to be used in another

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm writing a stored procedure that will bring back a lot of project information. Due to the structure of the existing DB it's been decided that this is the approach we need to take.

My base query is going to be a

`Select * from Projects where ProjectID = @projectID`

This will return something like

`ProjectID || Name || Component1Type || Component2Type`

After getting those results, I want to then query the Component1 and component2 tables and return the names of those components with something along the lines of

`Select Component1.Name from Component1 where ComponentID = Component1Type` 
(where this is the result of the previous query)

Which will return just the Name

After doing this for 3 or four more items, I want to append them back to the original query so I get one row back which is

`ProjectID || Name || Component1Type || Component2Type || Name1 || Name2 || etc...`

Any idea on how to do this? Do I want to use temp tables or is there a simpler way to go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Can you just JOIN the Projects table to the Component(s) table?

Comment: Does all the data have to be returned in a single row?  Also, is there a constant number of components in each project?

Comment: @msmucker0527 Is there a way to do the join without having to list out each individual column name for the join?

Comment: @Norla There are a constant number of components and it needs to be in a single row as they are all associated with a single project

Comment: @Jabsy does the answer provided by amit_g work?  This was the method I was refering to, i'm not sure what you mean by not having to list out each individual column name

Comment: @msmucker0527 That method works. I guess I was just over thinking things. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select P.*, C1.Name as Name1, C2.Name as Name2 
from Projects P
left join Component1 C1 
  on P.Component1Type = C1.ComponentID
left join Component2 C2 
  on P.Component2Type = C2.ComponentID
where P.ProjectID = @projectID
```

Comment: Thank you! Apparently I was just over thinking everything.